# Android EditText in TableLayout

Tags: android, xml

I have TableLayout with two columns (TextViews in left and EditText in right column). When I type too much in edit text it goes out of the screen. How to force wrap to the next line when width of EditText is to high?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.miebs.debt.PaymentDetail">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/payment_detail_table"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/column_1_right_margin"
            android:text="@string/Debtor"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/debtor_detail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/column_1_right_margin"
            android:text="@string/Amount"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Amount_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/column_1_right_margin"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/column_1_right_margin"
            android:text="@string/Date"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_detail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="showDialog"
            android:text="" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/column_1_right_margin"
            android:text="@string/Note"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/note_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/column_1_right_margin"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` & `android:layout_weight="1"` for `EditText`.

> Note :  `textMultiLine` won't work together with `numberDecimal`.

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/note_detail"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="textMultiLine"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in TableLayout android:stretchColumns="1" will stretch the EditText beyond the screen as and when the input is fed by user(More than 20-30 characters).

The problem can be resolved by using

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/payment_detail_table"
android:stretchColumns="0"
android:shrinkColumns="1">
```

For multiple lines in edittext use, `edittext.setLines(int);` in the activity file where 'int' is number of lines.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried it, but try adding `android:singleLine=true` to the EditText

Comment: But I want to have more than one line